# How can I check the environment variable in meteor

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

I'm a beginner of meteor, nodejs and mongo DB,

I knew meteor use local mongo db .

but I want to change it to mongolab ;

I started my web like this :

```
export MONGO_URL="mongodb://account:password@mymongolabdb:12345/mydb" 
meteor
```

I want to check MONGO_URL is right or not .

How can I do this ?

Comment: What exactly does this have to do with MongoDB other than the environment variable you want to read?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the server-side code you can check it as `process.env.MONGO_URL` and print it.

Comment: Thanks for answer !!
But how to print it ? 
on server side I wrote like this
`var mongourl = process.env.MONGO_URL`
but I still dont know how to pass a data from server side to client side (or page)

Comment: I got it !! just key it on termial `echo $MONGO_URL` , and termial will print it.

Answer (score 2):

Create a server method which returns `process.env.MONGO_URL` if you wish to have the value of this environment variable available on the client. On the client, make a call to this method. See [Meteor documentation on methods](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_methods) on how to do this.

Be extremely careful though with this kind of checking. You are exposing your database URL to the client. Make sure you check whether the logged-in user is allowed to view this value. In the method you can use `this.userId` which gives you the userId of the user making the call to your method.